# How to mock http POST with applicationType Json with Mockito Java

Tags: java, servlets, mocking, mockito

I want to mock http POST with json data.

For GET method I succedded with the following code:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

when(request.getMethod()).thenReturn("GET");
when(request.getPathInfo()).thenReturn("/getUserApps");
when(request.getParameter("userGAID")).thenReturn("test");
when(request.getHeader("userId")).thenReturn("xxx@aaa-app.com");
```

My problem is with http POST request body. I want it to contain `application/json` type content.

Something like this, but what should be the request params to answer json response?

```
HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);

when(request.getMethod()).thenReturn("POST");
when(request.getPathInfo()).thenReturn("/insertPaymentRequest");
when( ????  ).then( ???? maybe ?? // new Answer<Object>() {
    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        new Gson().toJson("{id:213213213 , amount:222}", PaymentRequest.class);
        }
    });
```

Or maybe "public Object answer..." is not the correct method to use for Json return.

```
usersServlet.service(request, response);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Post request body is accessed either via `request.getInputStream()` or via `request.getReader()` method. These are what you need to mock in order to provide your JSON content. Make sure to mock `getContentType()` as well.

```
String json = "{\"id\":213213213, \"amount\":222}";
when(request.getInputStream()).thenReturn(
    new DelegatingServletInputStream(
        new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
when(request.getReader()).thenReturn(
    new BufferedReader(new StringReader(json)));
when(request.getContentType()).thenReturn("application/json");
when(request.getCharacterEncoding()).thenReturn("UTF-8");
```

You can use `DelegatingServletInputStream` class from Spring Framework or just copy its [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/test/java/org/springframework/mock/web/test/DelegatingServletInputStream.java).

Comment: please, can you provide an example/solution to my concrete question :)

Comment: Got Compilation Error : -->  when(request.getInputStream()).thenReturn(new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));  --inputstream to  ByteArrayInputStream

Comment: Thanks , it works :). Maybe If u can see the other question perhaps  it will easy to you :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41541827/how-export-app-engine-datastore-data-to-localhost-using-gradle-task

Comment: what do yo mean with "request"?, how do you create that object in the unit test?

Comment: @JACA see original question: `request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class)`.